# compositions into odd number of parts, each part being even

Tags: generating-functions

The generating function for compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts so that each part is even is $(t^2/(1-t^2))^k$.
Is the generating function for the compositions with an odd number of parts each of which is even just $(t^2+t^4+t^6+\dots)^{2k+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but $2k+1$ is only one odd number, so sum over all odd numbers:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{t^2}{1-t^2}\right)^{2k+1} 
&= \frac{t^2}{1-t^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{t^4}{(1-t^2)^2}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{t^2}{1-t^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-t^4/(1-t^2)^2} \\
&= \frac{t^2(1-t^2)}{(1-t^2)^2-t^4} \\
&= \frac{t^2-t^4}{1-2t^2} \\
\end{align}